# How to show a second window on a button press C++

Tags: c++, windows

I've been doing a lot of small projects testing out some features before I make one big program that does everything.  This program has two identical windows.  They look like this:

```
hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
       0,
       szClassName,
       _T("Win1"),
       WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
       CW_USEDEFAULT,
       CW_USEDEFAULT,
       400,
       400,
       HWND_DESKTOP,
       NULL,
       hThisInstance,
       NULL
       );
hwnd2 = CreateWindowEx (
       0,
       szClassName,
       _T("Win2"),
       WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
       CW_USEDEFAULT,
       CW_USEDEFAULT,
       400,
       400,
       HWND_DESKTOP,
       NULL,
       hThisInstance,
       NULL
       );
```

One of the windows has a button that says "Show" on it.
[image]
<sub>(source: [000webhostapp.com](https://randomcounternet.000webhostapp.com/pastebasket/Win1.png))</sub>

When I hit "Show" I would like Win2 to pop up next to Win1.  I would like to do everything in the same `switch(message)` loop to avoid passing variables through multiple loops.  This is how I tried to make Win2 pop up:

(I only included the important part of the code)

```
switch(message)
        {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            case 1:
                ShowWindow (hwnd2, nCmdShow);
                break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work.  How can I make Win2 appear without a second `switch(message)` loop?

If my entire code it needed, here it is:  [CLICK ME!](http://randomcounternet.000webhostapp.com/pastebasket/Code/Multiple%20Windows%20Test.html)

Any help would be appreciated.

-Thanks

Comment: Test the window handle to see which window you are getting messages from.

Comment: Two possibilities come to mind: `nCmdShow` isn't set appropriately (you don't show what it is), or the window *is* being shown but it's underneath the original.

Comment: it is definitely not being shown.  Whenever i try to compile the code, it gives an error.  I will check my nCmdShow.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved by:

- Make `hWnd1` and `hWnd2` in global scope. I don't think your code works because
  you they are declared in `WinMain` but called from the window Procedure.

so a sample of the code will look like:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

HWND hwnd;               /* This will be Win1  in global scope*/
HWND hwnd2;              /* This will be Win2  global scope*/
// ...
```

In Window Procedure change `nCmdShow`to `SW_SHOWNORMAL` or `SW_SHOW`:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (LOWORD(wParam)){
        case 1:
            ShowWindow (hwnd2, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
                break;
   }
```

break;